# How can I create my own custom field?

Tags: custom-field

I know how to create a [custom form field](https://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_custom_form_field_type) if I am building a module/component/plugin but how do I build one of the Joomla! custom fields?

I can't find a tutorial and I think I'm probably Googling the wrong thing (disclaimer: other search engines are available... kind of)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you might be right there aren't direct official tutorials on this. But in the Joomla! documentation there is a hint.

A developer focused pdf from the creator of custom fields Allon Moritz called DPFields at this time and merged into Joomla! 3.7

https://joomla.digital-peak.com/images/blog/JDD16%20Custom%20fields%20in%20Joomla%20for%20developers.pdf

And another link on the official Joomla! documentation:
https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Adding_custom_fields/Implement_into_your_component

Comment: Also, if you're wanting to implement custom fields in your own component, then there's a tutorial step at https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Developing_an_MVC_Component/Adding_Custom_Fields

Comment: Thanks @alexandreelise are you saying that for `com_content` I should just be adding it to this area: `components/com_content/layouts/field/prepare/foo.php` because it is a custom custom field it won't be ovewritten by the core.

Comment: @Eoin it would be better to base your code on actual core custom fields and learn from the core custom. The simplest one is text field in JPATH_ROOT/plugins/fields/text learn from that one first then learn from other fields in the plugins fields group

Comment: In the final release of version 3.7 the fields got migrated to plugins.

Comment: Thanks @Laoneo so then I would simply duplicate a plugin and stat to write my own from there?  Is it just the plugin folder I need to duplicate?  It seemed like quite a lot more than that.

Comment: Nope, only the plugin folder. Then you have to discover it.